# How to sort by salary with Ransack and ignoring the dollar symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I am currently attempting to create multiple sort functions for my rails project using **ransack gem**. The issue that I am having with ransacker, is that I cannot read past the format of the string, because it has a ($) in some of the post and commas as well. What I would like to do is still sort the data attribute and ignore both the $ conditional dollar symbol and thousand position commas (may not be included in certain cases) & append current input from search box

For example:

string = "$30,000" -> parse to remove $ and leave only 30000 for the search engine to find the records that include the number & what was written in the search_form input (job.job_title). The code that I wrote is below, it may not be correct as I was trying multiple approaches. Final result: Ransack should search for "30000 marketing position"

rails view

```
<li>$30,000+ <%= sort_link(@q, :salary_between_30_and_40k, default_order: :desc) %></li>
```

job.rb

```
 ransacker :salary_between_30_and_40k do
    Arel.sql('SELECT * FROM JOBS WHERE job.hourly_wage_salary BETWEEN 30000 AND 40000')
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach here is to migrate your database so that salary details are stored as a numeric value rather than a string with formatting.

Comment: That may not work because a user can also use an hourly wage. Which includes a decimal place. I won't necessarily track that kind of data. But, they will show up in the search results by default.

Comment: Decimal values can also be stored in pretty much any SQL database.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thanks.